# Tensorflow-Custom Object Detection Api-Helmet Detection

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to detect person not wearing helmet using Tensorflow Object Detection Api. I am using 3000 images(1000 for persons not wearing helmet,1000 for persons wearing helmet,1000 for persons).I used SSD_mobilenet_v1_pets.config for training.
please find the PBTXT file:

```
item {
    id: 1
    name: 'withouthelmet'
}
item {
    id: 2
    name: 'withhelmet'
}
item {
    id: 3
    name: 'person'
}
```

In SSD_mobilenet_v1_pets.config file,(id:1 is for person but i have set id:1 to 'withouthelmet',id:2 to 'withhelmet',id:3 to 'person').

After training the model,it detects every person as'without helmet' and every car as 'person'.

[image]

[image]

Can you please let me know where the issue is.